# Is every separable Banach space with the MAP 1-complemented in a space with a monotone basis?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The question, already phrased in the title, looks like a classical problem from Banach space theory from the 1970s. Hence, my question is more of a reference request in its nature.

> Can every separable Banach space with the [metric approximation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_property) be isometrically embedded as a 1-complemented subspace of a space with a monotone basis?

Perhaps this could be already achieved in some renorming of Pełczyński's universal space.

Comment: I don't know, but do you know about Dor's negative result in the category of finite dimensional normed spaces?

Comment: Dor, L. E. A note on monotone bases. Israel J. Math. 14 (1973), 285–286.